# MaximizePartAction class in not there in package org.eclipse.ui.internal of eclipse indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-europa

we implemented a Plugin project in Eclipse Europa(3.3).Now we are porting it to Eclipse Indigo(3.7).So the Problem is "`MaximizePartAction`" class present in "`org.eclipse.ui.internal`" Package of Eclipse Europa 3.3 is not there in same package of Eclipse Indigo(3.7 ) so displaying build error message "`import org.eclipse.ui.internal.MaximizePartAction cannot be resolved`".

I suspect that it is moved to some other package of any plugin or same so requesting you to clarify me about this.i am very very grateful if anyone tells the answer and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse 3.4, there is a class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.MaximizePartHandler`. I assume the `MaximizePartAction` has been migrated to the commands framework in 3.4. You might consider using the handler instead.

In general you should avoid using classes from internal packages (i.e. containing a path fragment `internal`). They are considered as non-public API and can be changed without further notice (as you just experienced).